# kernel did not upgrade between 12.04->12.10->13.04

Tags: grub2, upgrade, kernel

Last week I did a dist-upgrade from ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 and after that from 12.10 to 13.04. Almost everything worked quite ok, but i noticed that the kernel was still 3.2.0.52 and not a 3.8 kernel.

I installed on an acer-aspire, 6GB memory, 250 GB partition on the HD and use amd64

The problem is in installing memtest86+ in grub. When performing an apt-get upgrade I get following:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for robert: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnuplot-nox gnuplot-x11
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdvdnav4
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/40.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,216 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 464427 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libdvdnav4:amd64 4.2.0+20130225-1 (using .../libdvdnav4_4.2.0+20130225-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libdvdnav4:amd64 ...
Setting up linux-image-3.8.0-28-generic (3.8.0-28.41) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.8.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.8.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.8.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.8.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.8.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.8.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-28-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.8.0-28-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.8.0-28-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up memtest86+ (4.20-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Generating grub.cfg ...
dpkg: error processing memtest86+ (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up grub-pc (2.00-13ubuntu3) ...
Installation finished. No error reported.
Generating grub.cfg ...
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.8.0-28-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-28-generic depends on linux-image-3.8.0-28-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.8.0-28-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.8.0-28-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.8.0-28-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.8.0-28-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.8.0-28-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.8.0-28-generic is not configured yet.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.8.0.28.46); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            Setting up libdvdnav4:amd64 (4.2.0+20130225-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.8.0-28-generic
 memtest86+
 grub-pc
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-28-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please advice. I already tried to reinstall memtest86+, grub, etc. but that did not help. Preferebly I do not want to reinstall the distribution

Many thanks

Robert

Comment: Post the results of this command `lsb_release -rcd; uname -rm; ls /boot` . Edit your question and add the results there.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually update the kernel by these Methods:-

From easier (1) to the more difficult (4):

1) Click on System > Administration > Update Manager > Click on Check button > Apply all updates including kernel.

2) Use Synaptic, search for linux-image and select the generic kernel version you want to install (i.e. linux-image-2.6.xx-yy-generic).

3) Compile the kernel.

4) Run the following Terminal commands to install a new 32-bit Ubuntu kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python-bs4

cd /tmp

rm -rf medigeek-kmp*

wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/medigeek/kmp-downloader/tarball/master -O 
kmpd.tar.gz


tar xzf kmpd.tar.gz

cd medigeek-*

python kmpd.py -d
```

The script at https://github.com/medigeek/kmp-downloader/ does not seem to allow choosing amd64 (64-bit) architecture. It only allows installing i386 (32-bit) architecture. This seems like a bug to me. Just press  instead of a number if you get stuck on a certain question in the python script.

If these step are not clear please read and apply this for detail help :- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel